# Getting Error when running rails s command in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, spree

Whenever I run rails s, instead of leaving the server running it immediately exits. I apologize if this is a ridiculous question, I am very new to rails and ubuntu. I am not sure if there is any more information you need.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/payment_method.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/payment_method.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/gateway.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/gateway.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/lib/spree/core/engine.rb:39:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/aaron/kmd/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /home/aaron/kmd/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/aaron/kmd/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/aaron/kmd/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please supply all steps taken prior to this point to setup your new rails application?

Comment: It looks like a problem with `ApplicationRecord`, upon which Spree depends. Please could you post the contents of your `app/models/application_record.rb` file?

Comment: I don't see an application_record.rb file inside of app/models/. All I see is app/models/concerns.

Comment: `ApplicationRecord` was added in Rails 5. If you don't have an `app/models/application_record.rb`, you can create one with the following content:    `class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base ; end`

Comment: Have you ran `bundle install` ?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 projects are supposed to have **ApplicationRecord** in their models which is used as a base class for all models.

It seems you are using **rails 5.0.1**.
**Spree** is gem which extend your current **rails app**; All it's models extends from your **ApplicationRecord**.

There should be a file named **app/models/application_record.rb** in your rails application. If not, create it with following content.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```